# Adding a light switch

Tags: switch, light

How do I add a light switch from the light, it never had one? Can I pigtail the wires from the light box? I need advice before moving forward..

Comment: Should add more information to the questions.  Guessing you have a pull string on the light and want to add a wall switch.  Sounds like you want a switch loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your exactly right, it's a pull string, The light has 2 black wires, 2 white and grounds!

Comment: I want to know if I can install a light switch, and what type of wire, box?

Comment: If you own the house, you probably can do yourself.  If a rental, most locals require the landlord to have an license electrician to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your area uses NEC 2011 or later, you need 4 wires (3 plus ground) from the light to the switch.

If your area requires use of conduit, then you need conduit. If not, cable will do. If metallic conduit, you don't need the ground wire.

If the circuit is 15A, you need 14Ga wire. If 20A, you need 12Ga wire. For cable, that would be 14/3 or 12/3 (the ground wire is there, but not counted in the /number)

The cable to the switch connects black to black, white to white, ground to ground to your existing wires. You remove the black wire connecting to the light now, leaving the white wire connected, and connect the red wire from the cable to the light. At the switch location, you connect black and red to the switch, and cap off the neutral wire unless it's a "smart switch" that needs neutral as well.

Comment: The cable has to be run inside the ceiling and wall, not clipped to the ceiling and wall :-) ... you'll need an old work box at the switch location. They come in plastic or steel,  Use a steel one, they are much more secure.  Some people just hate plastic ones.

Comment: +1 for adding the neutral at the switch location.

Comment: Hi, yes sir I own, it's a mobile home. I have changed kitchen outlets to GFCI and in bathrooms and the wires are 12g. I thank you very much for your expertise.